# Execute adb command programmatically

Tags: android

I need to simulate tap event on android using command. I use this code but it is not working:

```
public Boolean execCommands(String... command) {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = rt.exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

        for(int i = 0; i < command.length; i++) {
            os.writeBytes(command[i] + "\n");
            os.flush();
        }
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

where command is:

```
String[] commands = {
        "/system/bin/input tap 250 450",
        "/system/bin/input tap 250 450"
};
```

Comment: Do you have the right permissions in the manifest?

Comment: In my manifest I have this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />` Phone is properly rooted and acces in superuser is granted

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: No nothing, im trying to click on button. 250 450 are they coordinates. And on click listener I have log but onClick event is not trigered.

Comment: If I use it from console it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> envList = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, String> envMap = System.getenv();
for (String envName : envMap.keySet()) {
    envList.add(envName + "=" + env.get(envName));
}
String[] environment = (String[]) envList.toArray(new String[0]);
String command = "/system/bin/input tap 250 450\n" +
    "/system/bin/input tap 250 450";
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        new String[] { "su", "-c", command }, 
        environment);
}catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(tag, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
```

Comment: I tested and it only working for touch event. Not come to on click event.